# react admin create update delete not reflected on backend server

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-admin

I have a react-admin project served on the backend with `django-rest-framework`. I wrote a custom `dataProvider` in `src/dataProvider.js` referencing from [ra-data-django-rest-framework](https://github.com/bmihelac/ra-data-django-rest-framework/blob/master/src/index.ts) repo which looks like this

```
// in src/dataProvider.js
import { fetchUtils } from "ra-core";

export default (apiUrl) => {
     const httpClient = (url) => {
         const options = {
             headers: new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' }),
         };
         return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
     }

    const getOneJson = (resource, id) => 
        httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json
        );

    return {
        getList: async (resource) => {
            const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
            const { json, headers } = await httpClient(url);
            return {
                data: json.data,
                total: headers.get('x-total-count'),
            };
        },

        getOne: async (resource, params) => {
            const data = await getOneJson(resource, params.id);
            return {
                data,
            };
        },

        getMany: (resource, params) => {
            return Promise.all(
                params.ids.map(id => getOneJson(resource, id))
                ).then(data => ({ data }));
        },

        getManyReference: async (resource) => {
            const url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
            const { json, headers } = await httpClient(url);
            return {
                data: json.data,
                total: headers.get('x-total-count'),
            };
        },

        update: async (resource, params) => {
            const { json } = await httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
            });
            return {
                data: json,
            };
        },

        updateMany: (resource, params) => Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
            }))
        ).then(responses => ({ data: responses.map(({ json }) => json.id) })),

        create: async (resource, params) => {
            //console.log(params.data);
            const { json } = await httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/`, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
            });
            return {
                data: { ...params.data, id: json.id },
            };
        },

        delete: (resource, params) => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
        }).then(() => ({ data: params.previousData })),

        deleteMany: (resource, params) => Promise.all(
            params.ids.map(id => httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}/`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
            }))
        ).then(responses => ({ data: responses.map(({ json }) => json.id) })),
    }
}
```

My `App.js`

```
// in src/App.js
import React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource, Loading } from "react-admin";
import { ProductList, ProductCreate, ProductEdit, ProductShow } from "./components/products";
import dataProvider from "./dataProvider";

const apiUrl = "http://localhost:8000/api";
const dataProvider = dataProvider(apiUrl);

const App = () => {
  if(!dataProvider) {
    return <Loading />
  }

  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="products" list={ProductList} create={ProductCreate} edit={ProductEdit} show={ProductShow} />
    </Admin>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I am able to perform CRUD on the frontend side as [optimistic rendering](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html#optimistic-rendering-and-undo) is observed which makes me assume my `dataProvider` code is somewhat correct. The problem is the CRUD operation for `create`, `update` & `delete` is not reflected on the backend server i.e no `POST`, `PUT/PATCH` and `DELETE` requests are sent to the server. Example, sending a `POST` request to `http://localhost/api/products/` using Postman with request body

```
{
    "name": "Product 4",
    "category": 2,
    "restaurant": 3
}
```

return `201` created status and enters in the database. Performing the same request from react-admin doesn't fire the `POST` request in the backend server. Same goes for `PUT/PATCH` and `DELETE` requests. `GET` works fine though. What am I doing wrong/missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: From your description, would I be correct to assume that there are no errors shown within the console if you try any of the said http methods?

Comment: @MwamiTovi for your question, Yes, no error was produced. I did manage to solve this though. I will update the solution as a self answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: Ok, cool. Sounds great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting as a self answer to my question.
I had to pass `options` as an empty object parameter to the `httpClient` method.

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    const options = {
        headers: new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' }),
    };

    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
```

It was a minor carelessness on my part that troubled me for a few days