# react admin returns Unauthorized 401 error upon CRUD operations

Tags: reactjs, jwt, react-admin

I am working on a react-admin project. The backend is written using Django rest framework which runs on a docker container. The authentication endpoints for access and refresh tokens are written using `djangorestframework-simplejwt` and served at `http://localhost:8000/api/token/` and `http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/` respectively.

I have written my own `authProvider.js` and `dataProvider.js` for react admin. The `login` and `checkAuth` functions for `authProvider.js` looks like this

```
// in src/authProvider.js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export default {
    login: async ({ username, password }) => {
        const request = new Request('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        });

        const response = await fetch(request);
        if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }

        const { refresh, access } = await response.json();
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh);
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', access);
    },

    logout: ...

    checkAuth: async () => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');

        if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
            const { exp } = await jwt.decode(accessToken);
            if (exp > (new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 10) {
                return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
                const request = new Request('http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({ "refresh": refreshToken }),
                    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
                });

                const response = await fetch(request)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        throw new Error(response.statusText);
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(({ token }) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
                    return Promise.resolve();
                });

                return response;
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject();
    },

    checkError: ...

    getPermissions: () => Promise.resolve(),

}
```

Retrieving data works fine. But whenever I perform a create, edit and delete operation, I am automatically logged out with a 401 Unauthorized error. Error message from docker server log

```
Unauthorized: /api/products/2
"PUT /api/products/2 HTTP/1.1" 401
```

Error from browser console: `PUT HTTP://localhost:8000/api/products/2 401 (Unauthorized)`

Prior to adding `authProvider` and using docker container as backend, CRUD data mutations worked fine, using a local python venv as backend. So I assume the `dataProvider.js` is not responsible here.

I have not been able to figure this out for quite some time. Can anyone help me figure out what I might be doing wrong here? Thank you for your time.

EDIT 1: It seems the access token is not sent from the frontend during API request, hence the server returning 401 Unauthorized

Comment: The access token needs to be added to the request as an authorization header, something like `Authorization: Bearer <token value>`. Do you have anything in place to do that when you're sending the request?

Comment: @ShauntheSheep Thanks for your time. I referenced [this](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-in-memory-jwt/blob/master/demo/admin/src/dataProvider.js) file for my `dataProvider` code. Mine looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793728/react-admin-create-update-delete-not-reflected-on-backend-server). I do seem to be missing the part of adding the Authorization header on each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `dataProvider` to include the token (in a token, a cookie, or in a GET parameter, depending on what your backend requires). This is explained in [the react-admin auth documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#sending-credentials-to-the-api):

```js
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth'));
    options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000', httpClient);

const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```